# Prometheus + Kubernetes metrics coming from wrong scrape job

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I deployed prometheus server (+ kube state metrics + node exporter + alertmanager) through the [prometheus helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus) using the chart's default values, including the chart's default [scrape_configs](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/ead4e79279a972ec71f6a58dd04ef4491686efbc/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L796).  The problem is that I expect certain metrics to be coming from a particular job but instead are coming from a different one.

For example, `node_cpu_seconds_total` is being provided by the `kubernetes-service-endpoints` job but I expect it to come from the `kubernetes-nodes` job, i.e. `node-exporter`.  The returned metric's values are accurate but the problem is I don't have the labels that would normally come from `kubernetes-nodes` (since `kubernetes-nodes` job has `role: node` vs `role: endpoint` for `kubernetes-service-endpoints`.  I need these missing labels for advanced querying + dashboards.

Output of `node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}`:

`node_cpu_seconds_total{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-7.0.2",component="node-exporter",cpu="0",heritage="Tiller",instance="10.80.20.46:9100",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="get-prometheus-node-exporter",kubernetes_namespace="default",mode="idle",release="get-prometheus"} | 423673.44
node_cpu_seconds_total{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-7.0.2",component="node-exporter",cpu="0",heritage="Tiller",instance="10.80.20.52:9100",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="get-prometheus-node-exporter",kubernetes_namespace="default",mode="idle",release="get-prometheus"} | 417097.16`

There are no errors in the logs and I do have other `kubernetes-nodes` metrics such as `up` and `storage_operation_errors_total` so `node-exporter` is getting scraped.

I also verified manually that `node-exporter` has this particular metric, `node_cpu_seconds_total`, with `curl <node IP>:9100/metrics | grep node_cpu` and it has results.

Does the job order definition matter?  Would one job override the other's metrics if they have the same name?  Should I be dropping metrics for the `kubernetes-service-endpoints` job?  I'm new to prometheus so any detailed help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to add the "missing" labels by navigating to the prometheus service-discovery status UI page.  This page shows all the "Discovered Labels" that can be processed and kept through relabel_configs.  What is processed/kept shows next to "Discovered Labels" under "Target Labels".  So then it was just a matter of modifying the `kubernetes-service-endpoints` job config in `scrape_configs` so I add more taget labels.  Below is exactly what I changed in the chart's `scrape_configs`.  With this new config, I get `namespace`, `service`, `pod`, and `node` added to all metrics if the metric didn't already have them (see `honor_labels`).

```
       - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'
+        honor_labels: true

         kubernetes_sd_configs:
           - role: endpoints

         relabel_configs:
           - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
             action: keep
             regex: true
           - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
             action: replace
             target_label: __scheme__
             regex: (https?)
           - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
             action: replace
             target_label: __metrics_path__
             regex: (.+)
           - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
             action: replace
             target_label: __address__
             regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
             replacement: $1:$2
           - action: labelmap
             regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
           - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
             action: replace
-            target_label: kubernetes_namespace
+            target_label: namespace
           - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
             action: replace
-            target_label: kubernetes_name
+            target_label: service
+          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
+            action: replace
+            target_label: pod
+          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
+            action: replace
+            target_label: node
```

Answer (score 0):

From the scrape configs, the kubernetes-nodes job probes `https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/nodes/${node_name}/proxy/metrics`, while kubernetes-service-endpoints job probes every endpoints of those services with `prometheus.io/scrape: true` defined, which includes node-exporter. So in your configs, the node_cpu_seconds_total metrics is definitely come from kuberenetes-service-endpoints job.